# Is there a way to get the google chrome script debugger to break on exception?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to automatically break when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In newest Chrome it's possible.  I use 9.0.587.0 and in developer tools, scripts tab in left bottom corner is an icon that says click to pause on all exceptions.