# Rails 3.1 javascript phantom breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Since <strike>upgrading to Rails 3.1</strike> upgrading Chrome I've had problems using the Chrome Developer Tools.  There seem to be phantom breakpoints in the compiled application JS- the one which pops up most often for me is in `Sizzle.matchesSelecter` (line 4941, YMMV)

I haven't found any indication why the debugger thinks there's a breakpoint there, or any way to disable these breakpoints.  It's killing my workflow.

Is this common in Rails release candidates?  Is there a way to fix it?

***Edit***

Foot in mouth.

Comment: BTW- this only seems to affect chrome.  Firebug chugs merrily along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the chrome debugger set to break on any exception and you just need to turn that off.  See [Is there a way to get the google chrome script debugger to break on exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235546/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-google-chrome-script-debugger-to-break-on-exception) for details.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  I couldn't figure out why my laptop hit breakpoints all the time and my desktop didn't.  Took me a few days to realize what was going on.